# Are AsyncTasks terminated when stopping intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask

if I call `intent.stopActivity()`, and inside that Activity I called a AsyncTask on instantiation: is the task canceled when stopping the activity, or will it remain in background?

Comment: AsyncTask task is another Thread which runs in backgruond. If we terminates Activity, AsyncTask still runs...

Comment: You have to manage the lifecycle of an AsyncTask yourself. If you don't want to do it, use Loaders, they have managed lifecycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a `stopActivity` method in [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), but an `AsyncTask` is not automatically cancelled when its calling `Activity` is "stopped" whether truly being put in the stopped state or finished. If you want that to happen, call [`cancel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) on the `AsyncTask` in the appropriate lifecycle method in `Activity` like [`onStop`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29).